# Java parallelStream map misses records

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code and it behaves non deterministically sometimes. For example I pass 3 events there and the output have only two! Could you explain the reason of such behaviour?

```
public List<AbstractTransactionResponse> getEventResponse(final List<AbstractEvent> events){

        List<AbstractTransactionResponse> abstractTransactionResponses = new ArrayList<>();
        events.parallelStream().map(event -> {
            abstractTransactionResponses.add(getEventResponse(event));
            return null;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return abstractTransactionResponses;
    }
```

Comment: A) if you want deterministic behavior doing things in parallel isn't exactly a good start ... for example: you are using a list, but the order of your events doesn't matter? B) **setting up** that parallel stream comes at **cost**. You should only use it when you are processing hundreds, if not thousands of elements. Otherwise, the additional overhead is slowing down you significantly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because you are adding in parallel to a collection that is not thread safe, you could see missed entries, `null`s in your output list - it is really unknown what will happen. Instead fix your code:

```
return events.parallelStream()
             .map(this::getEventResponse)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`map` is supposed to not have any side-effects and your `map` operation obviously does, this is something the documentation prohibits. Also bare in mind, that `parallel` != `faster` in like 99% of the cases, you need to measure this, but I doubt you need it.